# Help with mvc conditional model validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i am using asp.net MVC 3 , in my module there are two types of payment modes 1. Wire transfer and 2. PayPal . Now depending on this type 1 and 2 the properties are to be kept Required or other data annotations ! how to do this ? 
for eg :

There is a Radio button for payment type ,

If type 1- i.e Wire Transfer is selected then these fields should be validated - First name , last name , email,beneficiary name , bank name , bank no , ifsc code etc 
if it is type 2- i.e PayPal then these fields are required - PayPal email .

This could be done by manual validation but is there some way to do it the right way with DataAnnotations?

Answer (score 4):

Simon Ince's blog post seems to be outdated.

There is no need to use DataAnnotationsModelValidator or do a DataAnnotationsModelValidator registration.

You can use the following code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple=false)]
public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable {
    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "'{0}' is required when {1} equals {2}.";

    public string DependentProperty { get; set; }
    public object TargetValue { get; set; }

    public RequiredIfAttribute(string dependentProperty, object targetValue):base(_defaultErrorMessage) {
        this.DependentProperty = dependentProperty;
        this.TargetValue = targetValue;
    }
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name) {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString, name, DependentProperty, TargetValue);
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context) {
        if (context.ObjectInstance != null) {
            Type type = context.ObjectInstance.GetType();
            PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(DependentProperty);
            object dependentValue;
            if (info != null) {
                dependentValue = info.GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null);
                if (object.Equals(dependentValue, TargetValue)) {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(value))) {
                        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) {
        ModelClientValidationRule rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ErrorMessage = this.FormatErrorMessage(metadata.PropertyName);
        rule.ValidationType = "requiredif";
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("depedentproperty", DependentProperty);
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("targetvalue", TargetValue);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

and the javascript side: if you are using jquery:

```
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('requiredif', ['depedentproperty', 'targetvalue'], function (options) {
    options.rules["required"] = function (element) {
        return $('#' + options.params.depedentproperty).val() == options.params.targetvalue
    };
    if (options.message) {
        options.messages["required"] = options.message;
    }
    $('#' + options.params.depedentproperty).blur(function () {
        $('#' + options.element.name).valid();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I've updated my example to use MVC 3, so that one is more up to date.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom validator attribute and decorate your model with it:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CustomValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var model = value as MyViewModel;
        if (model == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (model.WireTransfer == 1)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.FirstName) &&
                   !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.LastName);
        }
        else if (model.WireTransfer == 2)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.PaypalEmail);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then in your main Model:

```
[CustomValidation]
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: thnx !! but the problem is that in this case the client side validation wont be working ?

Comment: @bhuvin, no, it won't be working, but you could make it work by implementing `IClientValidatable`: http://devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2

Comment: @darin have tried it with other things but still it isnt working

Comment: @bhuvin, *not working* is not enough. What exactly have you tried? What exactly didn't work? The blog post I've linked in my previous comment is more than clear and it illustrates a working example. There is also [Part 1](http://devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-1) that you might read.

Comment: Thnx Darin !! Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

I have used the approach from [Simon Ince's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/04/conditional-validation-in-mvc.aspx) and it works well. Basically he creates a RequiredIf data attribute where you can specify the other property and value that must be true in order to make the current field required.